# Fouriercoefficient of the sawtooth wave help to find that the bessel equation gives $\sum \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

What are the complex fourier coefficients of the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by the $2\pi-periodic$ continuation of $f(x)=\pi-x$ , for x $0\le x < 2\pi$ ?

And how can one use that fact together with the Bessel function to show that $$\sum \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$?

Comment: what is the Bessel equation?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews  I dont see what to try.... @ cassandrao it was a typo, i meant the bessel function

Comment: @bakabakabaka How do you compute the Fourier coefficients? Can you do those integrals yourself?

Comment: did you mean the Parseval identity?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews yea i can compute these integrals, but I have troubles knowing what to do

Comment: @ cassandrao It says to conclude from the bessel equality that : $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fourier coefficients for nonzero $n$ are

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\hat f(n)
&=& \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} (\pi-t) e^{-i n t} dt \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{-i n t} dt - \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} t e^{-i n t} dt \\
&=& - \frac{1}{2 \pi} \left(\left[t \frac{e^{- i n t}}{- i n}\right]_0^{2 \pi} - \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{- i n t}}{- i n} dt \right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{-in} \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

and $\hat f(0) = 0$.

Thus applying [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) we have

$$\sum_{n=-\infty,n\neq 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi (\pi - t)^2 \, dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} t^2 \, dt = \frac{\pi^{2}}{3}$$

Comment: Pretty +1. Just in the last line's sum one has to take care that $\,n\neq 0\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio, thank you I don't know to do the latex. for that

Comment: Just did it for you, @cassandrao